# Prevent user to access certain page if not login ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

i'm trying to redirect user from welcome.page.ts where login button exist if they already logged in the will redirect to home.page.html, i have code in welcome.page.ts like this

```
  goHome(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home');
  }
  login(){
    this.service.login();
  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("user is not logged in");
        this.login();
      } else {
        this.goHome();
        return;
      }    
    });
  }
```

am i doing right?

heres my service code

```
login(){
    this.googlePlus.login({
      'webClientId' : '927898787134-spvfdmvm9apq0e1fo2efvvura8vqpid8.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offile' : true
    }).then(res=>{
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
      .then(suc=>{
        this.getData(suc);
        this.router.navigate(["/tabs/home"]);
      }).catch(ns=>{
        alert('Unsucessful');
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using AngulaFireAuthGuard. Without adding any special method, it handles everything for you without the need of additional code to your auth service or the page.

Instead of using a regular guard, you can directly add it into app-routing.module.

into app.module:

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard'; 

@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [
      AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: []
})
```

and into app-routing.module:

```
    import { AngularFireAuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo, redirectLoggedInTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

    const redirectUnauthorizedToLogin = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['login']);
    const redirectLoggedInToHome = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['welcome']);

    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule', canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToHome } },
      { path: 'welcome', loadChildren: './welcome/welcome.module#WelcomePageModule', canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToLogin } }
];
```

You can look at the details from here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Comment: so i don't need the check wheter user are already logged in or not?

Comment: nope, it's doing that for you. AngularFireAuthGuard is working with AngularFireAuth so you can leave that process to them :)

Comment: so i just edit where i wanted user should be in routes path?

Comment: i believe last part of the example is what you want, first path: if they are already logged in redirect them to home/welcome (whichever you have) second path: if they are unauthorized redirect them to login. important part is declaring the consts and adding them properly to `data: { authGuardPipe: ... } }` part

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is logic, but we need to see your services code.

Start trying to display messages with the console, in your function ionViewWillEnter() to test if the code is realy executed, try to display your user also.

Comment: yeah it is logic but doesn't executed right, when i logged in i still not redirected to home page

Comment: and if you mind, i'm kinda stuck at google login now to display the user data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233977/display-google-login-data-in-other-page-ionic heres my another question if you mind please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/prevent-access-to-pages-in-ionic-with-angular-route-guards/) example. You can use `canLoad` instead of `canActivate` which will be faster if you use lazy loading.

Comment: I do not know why but I changed canActivate to canLoad and it did not work. I am getting the following error: Invalid CanLoad guard. Ionic 5